# What is the difference of saveArg and saveArgPointee in gmock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am studying in the gmock. Now Im trying to mock the class named "task", like this:

```
class MockTask : public Task
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD3(Execute, bool(std::set<std::string> &setDeviceIDs, int timeout, PACKET_DATA *Data));
};
```

And I want to save the struct pdata when the task.excute is called, so that I can validate the pdata->member. This is my code:

```
PAKET_DATA data;
EXPECT_CALL(task, Execute(testing::_, testing::_, testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::saveArg<2>(&data));
ASSERT_EQ(data->resultcode, 0);
```

Is that correct? And what is the difference of saveArg and saveArgPointee?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can read in [gmock doc](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/actions.md#side-effects):

> SaveArg(pointer)   Save the N-th (0-based) argument to *pointer.
>
> SaveArgPointee(pointer)    Save the value pointed to by the N-th (0-based) argument to *pointer.

for your case, you should use `SaveArgPointee` - as you want to save pointed data (`PACKET_DATA *Data`) - not the pointer itself...

Look at this example:

```
struct SomeData { int a; };
class ISomeClass
{
public:
    virtual ~ISomeClass() = default;
    virtual void foo(SomeData*) = 0;
};

void someFunction(ISomeClass& a)
{
    SomeData b{1};
    a.foo(&b);
}

class SomeMock : public ISomeClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(SomeData*));
};
```

To test `someFunction` you need to check pointee that is being passed to `foo`:

```
TEST(TestSomeFoo, shallPassOne)
{
    SomeData actualData{};
    SomeMock aMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(aMock, foo(_)).WillOnce(::testing::SaveArgPointee<0>(&actualData));
    someFunction(aMock);
    ASSERT_EQ(1, actualData.a);
}
```

If you used `SaveArg` - you would just store pointer to local variable that  no longer exists:

```
TEST(TestSomeFoo, shallPassOne_DanglingPointer)
{
    SomeData* actualData;
    SomeMock aMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(aMock, foo(_)).WillOnce(::testing::SaveArg<0>(&actualData));
    someFunction(aMock);
    ASSERT_EQ(1, actualData->a);
}
```